# How can I modify the code generated by Class-Completion (ctrl-shift-c)

Tags: delphi, code-completion

I would like to modify class completion so that every method that is created contains a `raise ENotImplemented.Create;`

Does anybody know how to customize this behavior?

update:
I would like solution that is not dependent on a third parties.
From where does the IDE take its templates?
Is there a way through OTA?

Comment: See this: [delphi-ide-how-to-change-the-way-class-completion-works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/581386/576719). With ModelMaker Code Explorer (MMX) you will have an option to do what you want.

Comment: @RBA, ugh! You've posted the same link as LU RD.

Comment: I did not noticed. I deleted that comment

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I'm actually hoping for a more "IDE included" solution.

Comment: Then you will have to roll your own by the Delphi Tools and the IotaCodeCompletionServices interface.

Comment: Here is a link: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Obtaining_Tools_API_Services

Comment: Sounds promising, although I can't find more than the Help-Entry. The Interface definition is not in ToolsApi.pas do you have more information on that?

Comment: I am really interested on this also.

Comment: As a general introduction, see [Introduction-to-the-Delphi-Open-Tools-API](http://www.sdn.nl/SDN/Artikelen/tabid/58/view/View/ArticleID/3157/Introduction-to-the-Delphi-Open-Tools-API.aspx). Other than what's in ToolsApi.pas and a few samples like [Productivity_Sample](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE2/en/VCL.Productivity_Sample) and a link to [GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org/) where lots of code and examples using Tools Api can be found, I have not seen any documentation how to implement the `IotaCodeCompletionServices`.

Comment: Thanks for the links, but my problem is that there is no Information on IotaCodeCompletionServices. I guess its an Documentation Bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is that there is no way to actually modify the markup generated by RAD Studio's (Delphi/C++ Builder) Class Completion engine. I have exhaustively attempted to do this, to no avail.

I am told (from a very reliable source) that the Class Completion engine is hard-coded into the IDE, rather than templated, with no intended interface exposed through the Open Tools API to change its behaviour.

The best alternative solution is [ModelMaker Code Explorer](http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer/index.html) (be sure not to accidentally order "ModelMaker" instead as this is a totally different piece of kit).
As I understand it, ModelMaker Code Explorer essentially overrides the built-in Class Completion engine with its own, and provides the necessary exposure to customize the code markup as you require.

Comment: can you quote some official sources and the like ?

Comment: I shall ask my sources for permission... but I won't quote them without their permission (not sure if they told me this in some form of confidence or not)