# Delphi XE Source Editor Procedure/Function Sequence

Tags: delphi, editor, delphi-xe

I have switched from Delphi 7 to Delphi XE.

When I create a new procedure or function in a Unit, Delphi automatically places that function/procedure in alphabetical sequence within the unit.
e.g.

frm.FormClose; then frm.FormKeyPress; then frm.FormShow;

Is there anyway of disabling this?

Thanks

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527938/in-what-order-does-class-completion-put-its-results) can help you to understand better this feature.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to disable it.